# Matplotlib doesn't show both datasets points on the figure when I want to create scatter plot with

Tags: matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I'm sure that I've done all things right but in the end the result I got is a sccatter plot that only shows the second datasets data.

```
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
  ax1.scatter(train["ENGINESIZE"], train["CO2EMISSIONS"], color = "green")
  ax1.scatter(test["ENGINESIZE"], test["CO2EMISSIONS"], color = "red")
  plt.xlabel("Engine Size")
  plt.ylabel("Emission")
  
  plt.show()
```

Here You can see what's going on in my output in link below.
It shows only red data(test data) in the output.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please make your problem reproduceable by adding test dummy data and the image of your output. Links are not good mostly, because they are not static for ever or can be deleted. Answers and questions on stackoverflow should be written in a way so that they are valid for ever.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the "output link below", please? For now I can only imagine what you are describing.

Also it helps if both plots have the same axis. That is, both have the same x-axis and then they can vary on their y-axis.

If so:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot(kind = 'scatter', x= train["ENGINESIZE"], y = train["CO2EMISSIONS"], color = {'g'}, ax = ax)
df.plot(kind = 'scatter', x= test["ENGINESIZE"], y = test["CO2EMISSIONS"], color = {'r'}, ax = ax)
plt.xlabel()
```